# conditional statement does not appear to function correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Trying to jump to another view controller if the data entered on this controller is correct but jump is always happening even if the data is not correct

Tried different sites and resources and it looks like the code should work but for some reason, I cannot determine, it just not work.

```
    if loginok {
        passData = usrID + " " + pwdID
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "menu", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        messID.text = message
    }
```

expecting the "if" to control the load of the other view "menu" but "menu" is always loaded even when "if" is false.  messID is label on main view controller and it shows the message if data is not correct.  You can just see the message before the view changes and it does correctly show the error message for the part of the data that is incorrect, but then the view changes.

Just to note that the view does change for valid data input.

So currently it is always loading the the "menu" view once the button is clicked.

Comment: What is `loginok`? Post a larger piece of code.

Comment: Did you create a segue from the button to the other view controller in the storyboard? That would be executed unconditionally (unless you override `shouldPerformSegue`)

Comment: not sure as I am totally new to this.  I right clicked on the button with CTRL and dragged to the other view.  Is that then unconditional execution?

Comment: Larger chunk of code as requested (but it is not formatting correctly but appears fine in the edit pane).  loginok is just a check flag to see if the login was ok or not.
if (userID.text == nil || userID.text == "") && (passID.text == nil || passID.text == "") { message = "Enter a User ID and Password"
loginok = false }
else { 
if userID.text == nil || userID.text == "" {
message = "Enter a User ID"
loginok = false }
else { usrID = userID.text! }
            
if passID.text == nil || passID.text == "" {
message = "Enter a password"
loginok = false }
else { pwdID = passID.text! }
}